# Is there a way to deprecate or hide system framework API in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

For some context, I am using SpriteKit. I created an extension for `SKTexture`:

```
public extension SKTexture {
  var sizeInPoint: CGSize {
    return CGSize(size().width/2, size().height/2)
  }
}
```

Now I would like to prevent accidental usage of `size()`, because `texture.size()` is in pixel, which is never what I want in my game.

How do I deprecate a system API? Or is it even possible?

Note:

I know when I subclass the SKTexture, I can mark `size()` as deprecated IN MY SUBCLASS. However, this is not ideal because the superclass SKTexture still has `size()` API.

For example, we can still get SKTexture from SKTextureAtlas:

```
let size = textureAtlas.textureNamed("dummy.png").size() // avoid this!
```

Comment: Are you open to a SwiftLint based answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way to deprecate any API is to recompile the header file with the `@available (*, deprecated)` declaration for the selected method.

For system calls, for obvious reasons, I see no way to do this.
In your case, I would advise you to use tools like SwiftLint and add a rule to avoid calls, especially since SwiftLint allows you to mark these calls as compilation errors, not warnings.

UPD:

If you couldn't use an third-party libs, there is an solution.
Add Run Script Phase, and find keywords that should emit an "warning" or "error" message:

```sh
KEYWORDS="size\(\)|\?\?\?:|\!\!\!:" 
find "${SRCROOT}" \( -name "*.swift" \) -print0 | xargs -0 egrep --with-filename --line-number --only-matching "($KEYWORDS).*\$" | perl -p -e "s/($KEYWORDS)/ warning: using of size() is deprecated/"
```

Comment: is there an apple way of doing this? (without third party libs)?

Comment: You can simply add an Run Script Phase to your project and find some keywords and then emit "warning:" or "error:" message, read this for more - http://deallocatedobjects.com/posts/show-todos-and-fixmes-as-warnings-in-xcode-4

Comment: `KEYWORDS="size\(\)|\?\?\?:|\!\!\!:"
find "${SRCROOT}" \( -name "*.swift" \) -print0 | xargs -0 egrep --with-filename --line-number --only-matching "($KEYWORDS).*\$" | perl -p -e "s/($KEYWORDS)/ warning: using of size() is deprecated/"` - 
Here's what I was able to quickly write, and get warnings for using size()

Answer (score -1):

I guess it's impossible to deprecate a system API.

You may override a default behaviour:

```
public extension SKTexture {
  var sizeInPoint: CGSize {
    return CGSize(size().width/2, size().height/2)
  }

  override func size() -> CGSize {
    return sizeInPoint
  }
}
```